# How to insert multiple instances based on an array

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

We have two roles: *Admin* and *Customer*. There are a number of default users with email addresses following the pattern:

1. An *Admin* - *admin1@.com*, *admin2@.com* etc.
2. A *Customer* - *user1@.com*, *user2@.com* etc.

Then, we run the script for each combination (and in case with admins, it's done twice, because they're customers too).

```
insert into AspNetUserRoles values(
  (select Id from AspNetUsers where Email = 'AAA'),
  (select Id from AspNetRoles where Name = 'BBB'))
```

Now, based on my question, you can take a guess how it's resolved right now. For each new email, we add a statement or two. If we'd add a new role, we'd have to add a number of statement, possibly as many as the number of registered emails.

I sense there's away to declare a matrix on form:

> a@.com, role1, role2
> b@.com, role1,
> c@.com
> d@.com, role1, role3, role4

I've tried for a while but couldn't figure out the syntax, though. The actual DBA says it's not (easily) doable and that the script we have right now is as it's supposed to be done.

I suspect he's full of Christmas candy having been processed but, not being a DBA myself, I can't really argue, unless I have something that works. I also suspect that I didn't google the right way (i.e. I used wrong terms to describe what I want, due to my ignorance).

## Edit

Realizing that the question might be misleading, I'll give an example in speudo-code to illustrate my intention.

```
List<Link> links = new List<Link> { 
  new {a1,b1}, new {a1,b2}, 
  new {a2,b2}, 
  new {a3,b1}, new {a3,b3}, new {a3,b4} }
foreach(Link in links)
  ExecuteSql(
    "insert into Links values(
      (select Id from FirstTable where Name = link.A),
      (select Id from SecondTable where Name = link.B))"
  );
```

The part I can't figure out is how to declare such a list and how to loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Say we start by creating a temp table.**

```
-- Create temp table for user and roles
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    AspNetUser varchar(1000) ,
    AspNetRoles varchar(1000));
```

**2a) populate it from a File (eg `userroles.csv`)**

> a@.com,role1|b@.com,role1|c@.com,|d@.com,role1 role3 role4

Like this

```
-- Read from csv
BULK INSERT #temp FROM 'D:\userroles.csv'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR =','
    ,ROWTERMINATOR ='|');
```

**2b) OR do your own inserts in the script**

```
INSERT INTO #temp
(AspNetUser, AspNetRoles)
VALUES
('a@.com','role1'),
('b@.com','role1'),
('c@.com',null),
('d@.com','role1 role3 role4')
```

**3) Insert all combinations into the table by looking up the id's**

```
-- Insert all found combinations
INSERT INTO AspNetUserRoles
 SELECT users.Id, roles.Id
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT AspNetUser,  
         CAST ('<Role>' + REPLACE(AspNetRoles, ' ', '</Role><Role>') + '</Role>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  #temp
 ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/Role') AS Split(a)
    INNER JOIN AspNetUsers users ON users.Email = AspNetUser
    INNER JOIN AspNetRoles roles ON roles.Name = Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')

-- Clean up
drop table #textfile;
```

- *You can change delimiters `SPACE`, `,` and `|` to what you like.*
- *You may want to do errorchecking for typos!*